# selinux is preventing from execute access on the file centos

Tags: centos, centos7, tomcat

I want to launch the Tomcat service on CentOS with the cmdlet :

```
systemctl start tomcat.service
```

but i get the error

> Failed to start Apache ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
> (code=exited, status=203/EXEC).

and the log through the command  :

```
Journalctl -xe
```

is stating that

> Selinux is preventing (artup.sh) from execute access on the file
> startup.sh

given that i can start any other service on my CentOS what could be the problem for my tomcat service ?

Thank you

Comment: Do the [normal troubleshooting](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting).

Comment: or maybe turn on the permissive mode for SELinux ? please elaborate your ans.

Comment: You need to click the link and understand how to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The SELinux restricts binaries that can be used in ExecStart to paths that has system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 attribute set. Typically those are /usr/bin /usr/sbin /usr/libexec /usr/local/bin directories.

You need to move the script into one of this directories or change selinux policy to allow systemd to use binaries in the desired location as:

```
chcon -R -t bin_t /opt/tomcat/bin/
```

---

A restorecon will 'unfix' the above better to update the policy e.g.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t "/opt/tomcat/bin(/.*)?"
restorecon -r -v /opt/tomcat/bin
```

**UPDATE**

If java binary is not located in the standard location (custom JVM distribution), then you need to set *bin_t* label to it as well. For example, it your JVM installed in /opt/java, then:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t "/opt/java/bin(/.*)?"
restorecon -r -v /opt/java/bin
```

*NOTICE:* systemd ignores JAVA_HOME environment variable if it's not set in unit file.

Comment: seems promising direction, i will try quick

Comment: Actually the Exec error is still there returning control process with error 1

Comment: Check the location of java binary as well

Comment: as the JAVA_HOME path i use the /jre location (specified without the "")

Comment: It should have bin_t label as vell

Comment: how ? could you elaborate on the exact code adequate for the tomcat.service pls ?

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: Had this problem on an Oracle Cloud instance. Worked nice.